# Text editor using MVC pattern

Tags: java, beginner, mvc, text-editor

I am beginner in programming and recently I wrote an editor, inspired by the Notepad program, with all basic features any editor should have, like finding, undoing, copying, etc.

The problem is I do not "feel" OOP completely yet.  I wrote the whole program in a single class with few inner classes for actions, a frame for finding and replacing etc.  I only wrote one separate class for style settings, like textArea Color etc, yet implementation of this class was poor in my belief.

In the result I was happy with the fact I managed to create fully working notepad; however I cannot stop thinking how messy is the code underneath it. So I decided to rewrite it just for exercise and make it more structured.

I read about MVC pattern and I tried to apply it to my code. I wrote 2 view classes - Main View (with textArea and menuBar) and FindAndReplace frame in separate class.  Then I created model and controller.

Can you tell me if this makes any sense? Is this good implementation of MVC or I misunderstood it completely?

### MainGUI.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainGUI extends JFrame{
       
    public MainGUI(){
        initMainFrame();
        initMenuBar();
        initToolBar();
    }
    
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    
    void initMainFrame(){
        setBounds(300,300,300,300);
        add(textArea);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
       
    }
    
   public JMenuBar menuBar;
   public JMenu menuEdit;
   public JMenuItem findAndReplace = new JMenuItem("Find and replace");
    
    void initMenuBar(){
     
        this.add(menuBar=new JMenuBar(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        menuBar.add(menuEdit = new JMenu("Edit"));
        
        menuEdit.add(findAndReplace);             
 
    }
    
    void initToolBar()
    {
     /**
      *  toolbar
      */
    }
    
    public void setText(String text){  
        textArea.setText(text);    
    }
    
    public String getText(){
      return textArea.getText();
    }
    
    public void selectText(int selectionStart, int selectionEnd){
      textArea.select(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    
    }
  
}
```

### FindAndReplaceGUI.Java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class FindAndReplaceGUI extends JFrame{
  
    
    private JTextField findTextField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField replaceTextField = new JTextField(10);
    private JButton findTextBtn = new JButton("  Find Text  ");
    private JButton replaceTextBtn = new JButton("Replace Text");
    
    public FindAndReplaceGUI(){
        initComponents();
    }
    
    void initComponents(){
        
        setBounds(300,300,300,100);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
 
        JPanel TopPanel = new JPanel();
        add(TopPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        TopPanel.add(findTextField);
        TopPanel.add(findTextBtn);
        
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        add(bottomPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        bottomPanel.add(replaceTextField);
        bottomPanel.add(replaceTextBtn);
        
    
    }
    
    public String getTextFieldText(){  
        return findTextField.getText(); 
    }
    
    public JButton getFindButton(){
        return findTextBtn;
    }
    
    public String getReplaceFieldText(){  
        return replaceTextField.getText(); 
    }
    
    public JButton getReplaceButton(){
        return replaceTextBtn;
    }
    
    
}
```

### Model.Java

```
public class Model {
    
    
    
    private int selectionStart=-1;
    private int selectionEnd=0;
    
    void findText(String textToFind, String textArea)
    {
            selectionStart=textArea.indexOf(textToFind, selectionStart+1);
           
            if (selectionStart == -1)
            {                     
              selectionStart = textArea.indexOf(textToFind);            
            }
            if (selectionStart >= 0)
            { 
                selectionEnd=selectionStart+textToFind.length();
            }
            
            if(!textArea.contains(textToFind))
                selectionEnd=0;
            
             System.out.println(selectionStart);
             System.out.println(selectionEnd);
    }
    
    
    void replaceText(String textForReplacement, String textArea)
    {
    /**
     *  replace text method
     */ 
    
    }
    
    int getSelectionStart(){
        return selectionStart;
    }
    int getSelectionEnd(){
        return selectionEnd;
    }
    
}
```

### Controler.Java

```
public class Controler {

   
    MainGUI mainGui=new MainGUI();
    FindAndReplaceGUI finder = new FindAndReplaceGUI();
    Model model = new Model();    
    
    Controler()       
    {
        mainGui.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    public void control()
    {
    
        
       mainGui.findAndReplace.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             finder.setLocationRelativeTo(mainGui);
             finder.setVisible(true);  
           }
       });
     
       
       /**
        * Find and Replace control 
        */ 
       finder.getFindButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
              model.findText(finder.getTextFieldText(), mainGui.getText());
              mainGui.selectText(model.getSelectionStart(), model.getSelectionEnd());
           }
       });
    
       finder.getReplaceButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               model.replaceText(finder.getReplaceFieldText(), mainGui.getText());
           }
       });
       
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Controler().control();
       
    }
    
}
```

Does it make sense to put all ActionListeners to controller?

And I am wondering how should I access menu items from controller class? Does it make sense to set them on public (`MainGUI` and `FindAndReplace` are in different package) and calling them from in `Controler` class from  the object mainGUI directly.

I am still learning to code simple and clean yet I feel I am  still complicating things..

Answer (score 2):

as picture overview does looks like a beginner nice job, you miss something in `MODEL` part (a good model does not performs business logic: if you implement a `find()` method in `Controller`, you'll can modularize it to find between more files, just as example).

However there are some points you can focus on:

- access modificatiors of almost all variables and methods

  - when you need a constructor that always "`inits`", why don't simply create some objects and assign them inside the constructor ?
  - lack of "`final`" instance variables

After that, your `Controller` it's a "single tier" one.
Listeners can perform many actions but mainly can do themself   *look&Feel* modifications (as example: background color while performing some actions) but for complex cases a listener it's usefull if can call a `Controller` (or a static method) to make decisions.

Responsability to addListener can be moved to the GUI part, and GUI can link (instance variable) a reference of the Controller they wants to use.

Split classes in packages it's a standard business approach but, even if it's an underrated advantage, can let you manage the class visiblities better.